# Flag invalid attribute in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, jrubyonrails

I am trying to implement functionality wherein an attribute, once set, cannot be changed on an ActiveRecord model. To this end, I have written the following methods:

```
def address
 self[:address]
end

def address=(val)
 if new_record?
  self[:address] = val
 else
  errors.add(:address, "Cannot change address, once it is set")
  return false # tried return nil here first, did not work
 end
end
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I want the object to be invalid once I try to change an address, but I do not get any errors when I do `obj.valid?`

EDIT: The value is not changed once it is set, but I would like to get invalid object when I do the validation via obj.valid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do `obj.valid?`, it clears all of your errors, and then runs each of the validations in turn.  To have this produce an error on validation, you'll have to move that logic into a validation block.

Here's an example of one way to do that with an instance variable:

```
def address=(val)
  if new_record?
    self[:address] = val
  else
    @addr_change = true
    return false # tried return nil here first, did not work
  end
end

validate do |user|
  errors.add(:address, "Cannot change address, once it is set") if @addr_change
end
```

Comment: Duh! I should have thought of that.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I added a code example for posterity, in case somebody else comes along asking the same question. :-)

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks! This is what I was looking for for many hours for my legacy project.